# Is there an API in Android which can tell me which app is currently controlling the Audio channel?

Tags: android

Say my media player is playing in the background, and I am also talking on Skype, now if I have to play a voice navigation command, I should dim the music (but not Skype). And then play the announcement. Can I find which apps are using the Audio right now?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Before playing your voice navigation command, you should call AudioManager.requestAudioFocus(), so the other apps know that they should dim their streams or stop playing them, depending on the type of request you do.

Comment: I actually want to choose my action based on, whether the user is listening to something or not. Maybe I won't even play my announcement if the user is playing something. Can "I detect" the state of the audio?

Comment: i think that its even possible that more than one app is playing something